# Rotar QGraphicsItem - No lo hace sobre su centro

Tags: c++, qt

estoy intentando rotar un QGraphicsItem sobre su propio centro, de manera que no se mueva su centro, solamente gire X grados...no logro que suceda, se cambia de lugar, como si toda la scene girara pero el resto de los elementos no gira...pero él gira pero no sobre su centro. Les dejo el codigo para ver si me dan una mano. Gracias mil.

```
QRectF rect;
rect = engine->boundingRect();
QPointF center = rect.center();
qreal angle = grade;
QTransform t;
t.translate(center.x(), center.y());
t.rotate(angle);
t.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());
engine->setPos(t.map(engine->pos()));
engine->setRotation(engine->rotation() + angle);
```

Engine es el QGraphicsItem que quiero rotar sobre su centro...

Comment: No tengo experiencia en el tema, pero creo que http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Excelente @Trauma! Gracias por tú comentario y observacion!

Comment: Si resuelves tu problema, ¡ no olvides auto-responderte ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al apunte de @Trauma les dejo aqui como solucioné mi problema por si alguien le sirve. Todo el código de la pregunta lo reemplacé simplemente por lo siguiente:

```
engine->setTransformOriginPoint(engine->boundingRect().center());
engine->setRotation(engine->rotation() - grade);
```